Laravel cashier stripe "payment method"
I'm developing the APIs for laravel cashier stripe. am not a front-end developer and I don't have UI in my project, I'm testing APIs through Postman.
I have defined authenticated routes in api.php file in laravel
when I use checkoutSession method, works perfect,and method don't ask for the payment method  but doesn't store details subscription table and subscription_item table in the database,
so I changed this checkoutSession to new method.
I am getting this error:

The payment attempt failed because of an invalid payment method.

I tried this method works perfect in response, method gives link to complete subscription and don't ask for payment method but this method doesn't store payment details in the database.
What changes should I make in this code to store details in the database?
public function subscribe(Request $request)
{
 $user = $request->user();
 $plan = $request->plan;

 try {
    $checkoutSession = $user->newSubscription('prod_Q3sbrIX96e7e6', $plan)
        ->checkout([
            'success_url' => route('success'),
            'cancel_url' => route('dashboard'),
        ]);

     return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Subscription created successfully.',
         'checkout_url' => $checkoutSession->url,
    ]);
  } catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
    ], 500);
  }
    }

so to store details in the database I changed above code:
public function subscribe(Request $request)
{
$user = $request->user();
$plan = $request->plan;

try {
    $checkoutSession = $user->newSubscription('prod_Q3sbrIX96e7e7', $plan)
        ->create();

    // Retrieve the subscription data from Stripe
    $subscription = $user->subscriptions()->where('stripe_status', 'active')->first();

    if ($subscription) {
        // Store subscription in the subscriptions table
        $subscriptionRecord = Subscription::create([
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'type' => 'default',
            'stripe_id' => $subscription->stripe_id,
            'stripe_status' => $subscription->stripe_status,
            'stripe_price' => $plan,
            'quantity' => $subscription->quantity,
            'trial_ends_at' => $subscription->trial_ends_at,
            'end_at' => $subscription->ends_at,
        ]);

        // Store subscription item in the subscription_items table
        foreach ($subscription->items as $item) {
            SubscriptionItem::create([
                'subscription_id' => $subscriptionRecord->id,
                'stripe_id' => $item->stripe_id,
                'stripe_product' => $item->stripe_product,
                'stripe_price' => $item->stripe_price,
                'quantity' => $item->quantity,
            ]);
        }

        // Update user's table with payment method details
        $user->update([
            'stripe_id' => $subscription->stripe_id,
            'pm_type' => $user->pm_type,
            'pm_last_four' => $user->pm_last_four,
            'trial_ends_at' => $subscription->trial_ends_at,
        ]);
    }

    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'success',
        'message' => 'Subscription created successfully.',
        'subscription_id' => $subscription->stripe_id,
        'checkout_url' => $checkoutSession->url,
    ]);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    return response()->json([
        'status' => 'error',
        'message' => $e->getMessage(),
    ], 500);
  }
}

//but this method asks for payment method.
{
"status": "error",
"message": "The payment attempt failed because of an invalid payment method."
 }

